# Como elimino un registro de una tabla en PHO con MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, tablas, delete

he intentado eliminar un registro de una tabla, pero al dar clic en la acción el me dice que si la elimina y entra la (if) de la confirmación exitosa, pero no se elimina de la tabla. En teoría quisiera eliminar el Id_Articulos, pero no lo hace.

Código en donde se muestra la tabla

```
<?php 

include_once("Conexion.php");


$objConexion = Conectarse();

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    header("location:login.html");
}

$iduser=$_SESSION ['id_usuario'];

$artsql ="SELECT Id_Articulos,Id_Usuario_FK, Titulo_Art, Descripcion 
FROM tbl_articulos WHERE Id_Usuario_FK='".$iduser."'";

$resultado = $objConexion->query($artsql) or die($objConexion->error);

?>
```

Codigo que hace la eliminacion

```
<?php 

include_once("Conexion.php");
extract($_REQUEST);


$objConexion = Conectarse();


$delesql="DELETE from tbl_articulos WHERE Id_Articulos = '$_REQUEST[Id_Articulos]'";

$resultadodelete = $objConexion->query($delesql) or die($objConexion->error);

if($resultadodelete > 0){

    echo "<script>
    alert('Articulo Borrado con Exito');
    window.location = 'ConsultaArticulos.php';
    </script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script>
    alert('Error al Borrar Articulo');
    window.location = 'ConsultaArticulos.php';
    </script>";

}

?>
```

Este es el código de la tabla donde se consulta los artículos guardados por usuario logueado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta también esta el llamado al archivo de PHP para eliminar mediante una imagen

Comment: Está utilizando mal el extract. Modifique $delesql="DELETE from tbl_articulos WHERE Id_Articulos = '$Id_Articulos'"; Lo ideal sería utilizar parámetros en la consulta.

Comment: Buenas tardes, aun me sigue diciendo que el registro se elimino, pero no lo esta haciendo

Comment: Verifique los logs para ver donde se encuentra el error.